# bazel WORKSPACE file for external repository leads to missing #includes

Tags: c++, build, googletest, bazel

I'm trying to set up a workspace file for a project that uses googletest.  I'm following the instructions here: https://docs.bazel.build/versions/master/cpp-use-cases.html#including-external-libraries.

I have a WORKSPACE file that looks like this:

```
new_http_archive(
    name = "gtest",
    url = "https://github.com/google/googletest/archive/release-1.7.0.zip",
    sha256 = "b58cb7547a28b2c718d1e38aee18a3659c9e3ff52440297e965f5edffe34b6d0",
    build_file = "gtest.BUILD",
    strip_prefix = "googletest-release-1.7.0",
)
```

I have a BUILD file that looks like this:

```
COPTS = [
    "-I/usr/local/include",
    "-Iexternal/gtest/include",
    "-Wno-sign-compare",
]

cc_test(
    name = "gaussian_test",
    srcs = ["gaussian_test.cc"],
    copts = COPTS,
    deps = [
        "//:boom",
        "//:boom_test_utils",
        "@gtest//:main",
        ],
)
```

The #include section of my gaussian_test.cc file includes the line:

```
#include "gtest/gtest.h"
```

When I try to run the test I get

```
Models/tests/gaussian_test.cc:1:10: fatal error: gtest/gtest.h: No such file or directory
 #include "gtest/gtest.h"
```

In my main repository I solve this problem by manually installing googletest in /usr/local, but I'm looking for a more portable solution, and also looking to clear up a fundamental misunderstanding I seem to have about how the WORKSPACE file is supposed to operate.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The missing part of my question was the gtest-BUILD file, which contained the missing path information.